# None of the required 'libconfig++' found

Tags: cmake, containers, libconfig, rhel8

I have built libconfig dependency in RHEL8 container but cmake is unable to detect it.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:640 (message):
None of the required 'libconfig++' found
```

I can locate the object files at

```
STEP 11: RUN ls /usr/local/lib/
cmake
libconfig++.a
libconfig++.la
libconfig++.so
libconfig++.so.11
libconfig++.so.11.0.2
libconfig.a
libconfig.la
libconfig.so
libconfig.so.11
libconfig.so.11.0.2
pkgconfig
```

Linking after build is also done.

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig.git
RUN cd libconfig && autoreconf -fi && ./configure && make && make install && ldconfig -v
```

Comment: The error `None of the required 'libconfig++' found` is about inability of `pkg-config` utility to find `libconfig` package. Make sure that you have `libconfig.pc` file, which describes `libconfig` package for that utility.

Comment: It is present at `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libconfig.pc`

Do you think it need to be edited ? Below is the content of the file.
`prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libconfig
Description: C Configuration File Library
Version: 1.7.2
URL: http://www.hyperrealm.com/main.php?s=libconfig
Requires:
Conflicts:
Libs: -L${libdir} -lconfig
Libs.private:
`

Comment: Oops, sorry, you need `libconfig++.pc` file, not `libconfig.pc` one: the name of the file should be the same as the name of the package to search.